# Does the teaching of Christ that Christians will be punished after death undermine the idea of salvation?

Tags: luke, contradiction, sin, judgement

> 47 And that servant, which knew his lord's will, and prepared not himself,
>   neither did according to his will, shall be beaten with many
>   stripes.48 But he that knew not, and did commit things worthy of
>   stripes, shall be beaten with few stripes. For unto whomsoever much is
>   given, of him shall be much required: and to whom men have committed
>   much, of him they will ask the more. -- Luke 12:47-48

Does Christ speak of Christians literally being punished for the sins which they committed knowingly and those committed unknowingly in this verse, or this spoken of in a figurative sense, referring to a reprimanding, for example? Is there any indication in the text (besides, of course, that Christ is giving a parable) that this could be figurative? If it is literal, then how can one say that Christ died so that they would not be punished for their sins, but instead would have eternal life?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure why you identify the servant in the passage as a Christian.

Comment: @LukeSawczak If the servant is not a Christian, then Christ's parable, which begins in verse 42, makes no sense.

Comment: I disagree; I think Jesus' parables constantly tell us that the distinction is to be made in the future, at the master's return. Then people will be identified as goats or sheep, those who served him without knowing and who refused him without knowing, the sons who said yes but disobeyed and the sons who said no but obeyed, "assigned a place with the unbelievers" (v 46) or given a seat at the table, pulled up as weeds or stored as wheat. Until then we're all servants saying "Lord, Lord" but it's yet to be seen whether it's "in spirit and in truth" (John 4:32) or without obedience (Luke 6:46).

Comment: Couldn't have said it better @Luke.

Comment: @LukeSawczak So, you're saying that the passage in Luke is describing a separation of unbelievers from believers, and that the unbelievers are those who will be whipped?

Comment: Something along those lines. I don't know if it would even be clearly about belief/unbelief here as obedience or preparation. (Only a few parables seem to be about unconditional mercy.)

Answer (score 1):

The question inherently confuses and conflates so many things to begin with.

Eternal life, for example, is not an adverb (i.e. you eternal*ly have* life; as opposed to eternal life: life that is undending for those in possession of it), and as such doesn't preclude punishment before being admitted thereto. "Indeed," says St. Paul,

> **2 Corinthians 5:10 (ESV)**.. we must all appear before the judgment seat of Christ, so that each one may receive what is due for what he has done in the body, **whether good or evil.**

Salvation is from eternal damnation, not from suffering. In fact, Scripture makes suffering a prerequisite to receiving eternal life:

> **Romans 8:17 (ESV)** and if [we are] children, then heirs—heirs of God and fellow heirs with Christ, **provided we suffer with him in order that** we may also be glorified with him.
>
> **Luke 9:23 (ESV)** And he said to all, “If anyone would come after me, let him **deny himself and take up his cross** daily and follow me.

Then you distinguished between a *punishment* and a *reprimand for wrongdoing*. That is to say, between the genus of punishment and a species of that genus, namely, reprimand—a form of punishment.

Then you implied a parable wherein punishment is describes cannot refer to  real punishment, leaving one to wonder: what does real but figurative punishment *to be warned against* (the moral of the story .. of the parable) look like? Or how could Jesus refer to real punishment in a parable?

Yet we have countless explicit examples where Jesus steps out of the parable and explains in a rather lucid manner, e.g.:

> **Matthew 18:21:35 (ESV)** Then Peter came up and said to him, “Lord, how often will my brother sin against me, and I forgive him? As many as seven times?” 22 Jesus said to him, “I do not say to you seven times, but seventy-seven times.
>
> 23 “Therefore the kingdom of heaven may be compared to **a king** who wished to settle accounts with **his servants**. 24 When he began to settle, one was brought to him who owed him ten thousand talents. 25 And since he could not pay, his master ordered him to be sold, with his wife and children and all that he had, and payment to be made. 26 So the servant fell on his knees, imploring him, ‘Have patience with me, and I will pay you everything.’ 27 And out of pity for him, the master of that servant released him and forgave him the debt. 28 But when that same servant went out, he found one of his fellow servants who owed him a hundred denarii, and seizing him, he began to choke him, saying, ‘Pay what you owe.’ 29 So his fellow servant fell down and pleaded with him, ‘Have patience with me, and I will pay you.’ 30 He refused and went and put him in prison until he should pay the debt. 31 When his fellow servants saw what had taken place, they were greatly distressed, and they went and reported to their master all that had taken place. 32 Then **his master summoned him and said to him, ‘You wicked servant! I forgave you all that debt** because you pleaded with me. 33 And should not you have had mercy on your fellow servant, as I had mercy on you?’ 34 And in anger his master delivered him to the jailers, **until** he should pay all his debt. 35 **So also my heavenly Father will do to every one of you, if you do not forgive your brother from your heart.”**

Cf. Mt 5:25-26.

Notice again: the wicked servant **was** himself **forgiven**, but would not forgive others. Clearly the King is Jesus, per St. Paul, and "his servants" are His people. That is, this one is 'saved,' but he must be punished "until" all is aright again—until all accounts are 'settled.'

You can be forgiven your sins but still be punished:

> **Revelation 3:19 (ESV)** Those whom I love, I reprove and discipline, so be zealous and repent.
>
> **1 Corinthians 11:32 (ESV)** But when we are judged [i.e. punished] by the Lord, we are disciplined so that we may not be condemned along with the world.

If God forgave you your sins but you didn't receive any bad consequences, you would not be changed as a person—you would be the same person inclined to the same evil. That is to say, your guilt as been forgiven, but you need changed if for no other reason than to no longer be the kind of person that does things which make you guilty.

There is the eternal punishment which every wilful sin merits, but there is also the temporal. For example:

> **2 Samuel 12: 13-14 (ESV)** David said to Nathan, **“I have sinned against the Lord.”** And Nathan said to David, **“The Lord also has put away your sin;** you shall not die. **14 Nevertheless,** because by this deed you have utterly scorned the Lord, **the child who is born to you shall die.”**

There is still a sense of justice in which God demands a lesser punishment than the eternal, even though the eternal has been forgiven (Hell for all eternity). Of which this is just one example.

So in summary: No, salvation does not preclude suffering, but rather entails it.

Comment: I used eternal life as a synonym for salvation or forgiveness, as I assume that John 3:16 does; I should have made that clear. Concerning Romans 8:17, it is clearly speaking of suffering on Earth, and not punish necessarily, as made clear by verse 18. Luke 9:23 does not speak of punishment, either. Moreover, you say that a reprimand is a punishment, although it is not, seeing as punishment is the infliction of a penalty, or a compensation, while a reprimand is simply a condemnation. The shame of a reprimand might be seen as punishment, but the reprimand itself is not punishment necessarily.

Comment: I'll continue my response later. God bless.

Comment: Again you have conflated my argument from Scripture that eternal life cannot preclude suffering doesn't mean the Scriptures quoted mention suffering in the world to come. And eternal life is a synonym for ultimate forgiveness, but even if this was falsely assumed to be unconditionally applied indefinitely to all future sins (i.e., e.g., even if you don't repent of the sin committed in the future), and the word eternal was then taken adverbially, this still wouldn't imply not reprimand/correction/sanctification, all of which involve suffering.

Comment: Jesus hints at this relationship when He says repenting and being zealous is equivalent to what is being avoided by so doing (i.e. His discipline). But make no mistake: eve if you think eternal life means *you will always have* that life or cannot *forfeit* it, or have no *absolute duty* to produce fruit, good works, must avoid evil, not live according to the flesh, *must forgive others* etc., this still wouldn't yield the notion that because the eternal debt for sin has been paid, you are now free from all consequences. Whereas I showed you King David's example.

Comment: Jesus' 'dont sin or something worse will happen to you' also does away with this interpretation of forgiveness or eternal life as precluding any kind of punishment.

Comment: Punishment is "physical"; that is, pain or death is involved. This seems to be so in every case found in Scripture. There is also a difference between mere punishment and chastening. You send a thief to jail regardless of whether or not he will feel guilty for stealing, in order to perform justice; but you punish a child for causing mischief so that he knows not to do that again. That is chastening. Nevertheless, you punish a child even if he does not feel guilt for his misdeed, in order to perform justice. Revelation 3:19 and 1 Corinthians 11:32 are referring to that chastening.

Comment: This chastening, although it is punishment, is not punishment in the same way that retributive justice is, because it is done with the goal of instructing. The punishment of hell is not done to instruct, and my question concerning Luke 12:47-48 assumes that this punishment is not to instruct, seeing as the suggestion is that the punishment takes place after death. Chastening is not necessary after death, although I am perhaps wrong about that.

Comment: Chasten, Merriam-Webster: #1 definition "to correct by punishment or suffering." If the chastening is to be avoided (by not behaving so as to need it), surely that counts as suffering.

Comment: The intention of a thing does nothing to take away or change the reality of the thing. (E.g. the killing of another person caused by someone else directly: manslaughter vs. murder, but still someone has been killed by another). "Luke 12:47-48 assumes that this punishment is not to instruct, seeing as the suggestion is that the punishment takes place after death" How does that comport with 2 Cor 5:10?

Comment: The intention of a deed does not change the physical effect of that deed, but it does change what deed is. If a person kills someone else intentionally, they have committed murder, but if they did it accidentally, it was an accident and no vice. The victim is dead either way, of course. It is the same with chastening and retributive punishment. What I said about Luke 12:47-48 agrees with 2 Corinthians 5:10.

Comment: If we are to "recieve what is due" that is retributive. When Jesus says in Revelation, "Behold, I will cast her into a bed: and they that commit adultery with her shall be in very great tribulation, except they repent from their deeds. And I will kill her children with death, and all the churches shall know that I am he that searcheth the reins and hearts, and I will give to every one of you according to your works. .." that's exactly what happened with David who was obviously forgiven as Nathan said: and as Nathan notes, his forgiveness doesn't preclude a punishment.

Comment: 2 Corinthians 5:10 is vague, and does not make clear the exact nature of what is being received, although it is clear that it is received because of either good deeds which were done, or evil ones. My question is this: What is the point of the sacrifice of Christ if we are going to be punished for our sins anyway? What was the purpose of Christ's sacrifice? Was it only to save us from one type of punishment, to suffer another one, smaller in intensity?

Comment: What does Christ give for good deeds but reward? What is there left to impart for the opposite of good, then? Only punishment. I believe it is quite clear indeed. In fact, the context demands this: "we labour,.. to please him: for we must all.. [be judged]. Knowing therefore the fear of the Lord.. [etc.]"

Comment: What's the point in Christ's sacrifice??? Reconciliation with God and the forgiveness of sins. Whereas modern Evangelicals might hear that and think it happens at once permanently and you never need to ask for real forgiveness again or something, this was simply alien to Christians prior. Christians have never believed these descriptions of ultimate reconciliation happen immediately and forever just because they were **accomplished** once and forever by Christ. For example, does Christ really intend for you to forgive your brother or He will revoke yours, or is He joking?

Comment: In other words, salvation has always been synergistic, not monergistic. Monergistic doesn't only mean God is the author and finisher of your salvation, which synergists believe, but a step further, they believe that man has no positive input into his own salvation. Whereas this contradicts the Bible. It teaches that God enables those in Christ to definitely do positive, God-pleasing things, which will determine their reward in heaven, among other things.

Comment: When does this punishment take place, is the question. Does it take before or after death? How are our sins forgiven if we are still punished like unbelievers are, but with less intensity? I, by the way, confess my sins all the time, in line with 1 John 1:9.

Comment: Compare 2 Cor 5:10 with 1 Cor 3:12-17. They both place it at the Judgement Seat of Christ. We don't appear before the Judgement Seat of Christ until our judgement after death. Moreover, we know from experience that sanctification isn't always perfectly complete upon our death. It hurts to change while alive and will hurt to change every time the same happens to the same person. If God didn't need you to change as a person, freely, willingly, He wouldn't wait on you growing up to Christ, but would 'zap' you perfect and send you to heaven.

Comment: You imply our being punished means we haven't been forgiven, despite the Scriptural quote about David's temporal punishment even though he was forgiven for the eternal. It we weren't unforgiven it would mean we have to undergo the punishment AND we are not reconciled on top of that. But you can say, 'I forgive you, but you must do some tiny thing as punishment.' That's a mercy in comparison to unforgiveness. And it's not required on their part, but is free choice on their part, and out of their charity. Jesus has a 'yoke' remember. A real one. A light one. But a real one.

Comment: If you steal, for example, you must return what you stole, because to say you are sorry while not restoring something in your power to restore, you are essentially lying. If you offend God, then say you are sorry, but then refuse to do the opposite or equivalent to the opposite of what sin you committed out of sorrow, you are also essentially lying: for you could take back this offense against God which He has forgiven you, by willingly choosing not that evil, but a good in its stead. This is the essence of the 'punishment' part in forgiven sins. It's just justice.

Answer (score 0):

The section of Luke 12:41-48 starts with Jesus being asked whether this parable was intended for His followers alone or for everyone? He replies in an indirect way  describing the participants of focus as those attending to His household (therapeia), providing them sustenance in the seasonal cycles (kairos) (2Tim.4:2). The Lords coming can have two applications; an immediate judgement that can occur at any time, or at His second coming (1Pet. 4:17). Those in the first resurrection are given rewards for their overcoming, not judgements for their failings, so this parable cannot refer to the resurrection (Rev. 20:4,5). He adresses 3 different groups of the called in this age with the responsibility to preach His gospel. The first one, thinking the Lord delays His personal judgement, instead turns to carnal pursuits and abuses the brethren making merchandise of them (2 Pet.2:3). He loses his understanding and responsibilities and becomes as one who does not know God (1 Pet.5:2). The second becomes lazy and negligent not maintaining his relationship with God (Rev.3:17). It takes extreme trial for him to be brought to his senses. The third, who acted honorably according to what he understood, but lacked depth in his understanding of Gods plan, experiences basic trials. This parable is not about being punished after ones death at the resurrection.